# Theoretical expression for the capacitance of interdigitated electrodes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

I am trying to determine the capacitance of interdigitated electrodes, like [these](https://doi.org/10.1088/2053-1591/ac7851):

[image]

According to the paper, it can be calculated by:

$$C=\varepsilon \frac{(2l_0-a+2w_0)t_0}{d_0}(2n-1) \tag{1}$$

Where $a$ is the total width of the interdigitated electrodes, $w_0$ is the width of electrodes, $l_0$ is the length of the electrodes, $t_0$ is the thickness of the electrodes, and $n$ is the number of electrode pairs.

I wonder how this expression can be derived and, for this purpose, I am comparing it to the expression of a plane-parallel plates capacitor, $C=\varepsilon A/d_0$. I see that each pair of electrodes forms a plane-parallel capacitor, so there will be $(2n-1)$ parallel capacitors and $C=C_1(2n-1)$, white $C_1$ the capacitance of a single pair. Since $t_0$ is the thickness of the electrodes, $(2l_0-a+2w_0)$ must be the length of each plate so that when multiplied by $t_0$ it gives the area. However, where does this factor come from? I don't see its geometrical meaning.

Comment: The approximate formula you quote for a plane parallel capacitor assumes that the plate spacing is small compared to the plate dimension, so that the "fringing" field may be neglected. But this capacitor's field is all fringe.

Comment: Honestly you may just need to chase down the references.  The paper you link cites references [6], [39], and [42].  Paper [6] also appears to have the formula;  it doesn't give a derivation either (as far as I can tell) but references two earlier works.  In principle you can trace the claim back to its source this way.

Comment: I don't think this expression is appropriate for this structure, the author of the paper doesn't seem to understand this formula. I have read another literature and although the original derivation was not provided, what I can confirm is that this factor corresponds to the overlapping part of the electrodes (because the electric field is mainly concentrated here)[link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sna.2007.06.014). Therefore, if the width of the part connected to the interdigitated electrodes (I don't know what they are called) is no longer $w_0$, this factor should also be changed accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I tried! I checked about 5 references, but they all use this formula without derivation. I found this strange since I would expect the $(2l_0-a+2w_0)$ to have a simple geometrical meaning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it was indeed pretty geometrical. The problem is that in the diagram it is not specified that the width of the horizontal bars is also $w_0$. In that case, in the absence of overlapping, $2l=a-2w_0$. If a length $L$ is overlapped, then $2l-L=a-2w_0$, and therefore the overlapped length is $L=dl-a+2w_0$. So the formula is assuming $(2n-1)$ capacitors in series each of them with a capacitance $C_1=\varepsilon Lt_0/d_0$, as I initially thought.